# MS Access - how can I remove certain values from one field based on another field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query with 2 fields: `tqty` and `Comments`. This query is used to generate how much we need to transfer materials by doing the calculation "requirements" - "inventory" (pseudocode).

The current data looks like this when populated:

```
tqty              Comments
0                Please check manually
100
200
300
0                Please check manually
0
0
```

You'll notice that the 2 zeros at the bottom do not have the phrase "Please check manually". This is because when the query did the calculation `((([qty_on_hand]-[qty_req])/[qty_req])<=0.2)` the value was not less than or equal to 0.2. **This is normal**. Some values will have this. *However* I want to remove the zeros under `tqty` that do not have this phrase under `Comments`. How would I go about doing this?

what I want the query to do

```
tqty              Comments
0                Please check manually
100
200
300
0                Please check manually


SELECT 
qry_BENJobItems.item,
dbo_item.description, 
IIf(([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])<0,0,([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])) AS tqty,
"" AS [Transfer Pallets], 
"" AS Location, 
"" AS [Lot Code], 
dbo_item.product_code, 
Switch(((IIf(([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])<0,0,([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])))=0) And ((([qty_on_hand]-[qty_req])/[qty_req])<=0.2),"Please check manually") AS Comments

FROM (qry_BENJobItems INNER JOIN qry_BENInventory ON qry_BENJobItems.Item = qry_BENInventory.Item) INNER JOIN dbo_item ON qry_BENJobItems.Item = dbo_item.Item

GROUP BY qry_BENJobItems.item, dbo_item.description, IIf(([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])<0,0,([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])), dbo_item.product_code, Switch(((IIf(([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])<0,0,([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])))=0) And ((([qty_on_hand]-[qty_req])/[qty_req])<=0.2),"Please check manually")

HAVING (((dbo_item.product_code) Not Like "RM-CANDY" And (dbo_item.product_code) Not Like "FG - CLRM" And (dbo_item.product_code) Not Like "RM-SubAssy"))

ORDER BY qry_BENJobItems.item;
```

Comment: Can you show us what the table structures look like? All we can see is the `tqty` and `comments` fields.

Comment: @Tingo Which tables?